# libgdx Resizing an Image with Border

Tags: java, libgdx

i have an image with a 5px black border what i will use for serveral buttons.
The only problem is, that the buttons have different sizes.
Is there a way to resize it properly?
The only way i can figure it out, is to split it in individually pieces.

Eg.:
The Image is 200x200 and the Button 200x200 -> Border is ok.
The Image is 200x200 (the same) and the button 400x200 -> Border is stretched.

Comment: how do you make the border? is it part of texture or what?

Comment: If you use it for buttons, I would recommend ninepatches, take a look at the libgdx wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches

Comment: If you want to use one background for many different sized buttons, it might be worth looking into [9 patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). *"An example use of a NinePatch is the backgrounds used by standard Android buttons — buttons must stretch to accommodate strings of various lengths"*- From above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last Months i´ve learned very much about libgdx and i must say that the use of ninepatches are the best solution.

[See here to learn more about 9patch in libGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches)

Answer (score 1):

resize an image to diffrerent image ratio without stretch i don't know i someting like taht could exist , but here what i will do to solve your problem

this is your what is happening
[image]

to solve this i would use an image border full black and draw it under the image like the picture
[image]
when re-size it instead of 400X200 i will decrease it with a little margin like 380x200

hope this was clear and helpfull

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have made a 1x2 Image with the two different colors (background, border). Then I have stretched the single Pixels (after i splitted the Texture in two Textureregions) in the wished size.